# 8-puzzle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

When I run my 8-puzzle program I keep getting, "GC overhead limit exceeded". I have tried adding more memory to the JVM but that didn't help.

Here is the method which is the problem:

```
    public void search() {
    addToQueue(start, null);// add root
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        currState = queue.removeFirst();


        if (goal.equals(currState)) { 
            solution = true;
            printSolution(currState);
            break;

        } else {
            a = currState.indexOf("0");

            // left
            while (a != 0 && a != 3 && a != 6) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a - 1) + "0"
                        + currState.charAt(a - 1)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToQueue(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // up
            while (a != 0 && a != 1 && a != 2) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a - 3) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a - 2, a)
                        + currState.charAt(a - 3)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToQueue(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // right
            while (a != 2 && a != 5 && a != 8) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a)
                        + currState.charAt(a + 1) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a + 2)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToQueue(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // down
            while (a != 6 && a != 7 && a != 8) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a)
                        + currState.substring(a + 3, a + 4)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1, a + 3) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a + 4);
                addToQueue(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Start is a String that I read in from a file .txt.
It will work for some problems, but some will produce this error.

```
    private void addToQueue(String newState, String oldState) {
    if (!levelDepth.containsKey(newState)) {
        newValue = oldState == null ? 0 : levelDepth.get(oldState) + 1;
        unique++;
        levelDepth.put(newState, newValue);
        queue.add(newState);
        stateHistory.put(newState, oldState);

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any more to the error message? Does it give you a line number/method name, or does it indicate any objects?

Comment: Is you app processing for an excessively long time?  Are you traversing a large data set?

Comment: @Taylor it does process for an extended period of time.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard the error message says it is a problem with the search() method, more specifically it is when the nested while loops are being executed.

Comment: Maybe you have a logic problem that is infinitely loading the queue. Examining your code...

Comment: One thing that occurs to me as a possibility: it looks like you are creating a _ton_ of strings. You might want to find a different way to store state. I don't know if that's the cause of your problem, but all those string concatenations/reassignments are a bit of a red flag.

Comment: I'd refactor to use a StringBuffer rather than concatenation, and see if that helps.

Comment: Disclaimer for the previous comment: I've never encountered this error, so I could be way off. Hopefully someone with more experience can shed more light. Definitely an interesting problem. I'm curious to know the explanation.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Im not sure what you mean or how I would implement that.

Comment: @user3000406 google is your friend on things like that

http://www.java-forums.org/java-lang/7705-how-use-stringbuffer-class.html

Comment: @user3000406 Rather than doing `String nextState = foo + bar + something + else` you'd instantiate a StringBuffer with `foo`, then call its `append()` method to add `bar`, `something` and `else` to it - that won't result in tons and tons of strings being created.

Comment: Your loop structure seems weird to me, and I'm not sure you need a queue.  It seems you have either finished your processing (goal.equals(currState)) or you add several items to your queue (within all those while loops).  Your queue seems to only ever grow, but you seem only interested in the first item in the queue. I have a hunch you're hanging on to a ton of data you don't need.

Comment: Also, all your inner while loops hang off of "a" but I don't see its value changed within those same loops.  Are you sure you don't just have an infinite loop?  have you debugged this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is due to the GC thread hogging 98% or more of processor time.

Easiest thing to do is to break your method down into several different methods, that way the method local strings can be collected.

Secondly use StringBuffers for your concatenations, string concatentaion will slow things down considerably.

There are other things you could potch with, concurrent GC etc but helping the jre out with you method structure is the most important.